# PHP error cannot view on Mac

Tags: php, macos, apache

I cannot view PHP error on Apache of my mac because every time when I changed from php.ini file to display_error On. But when i restart and open the php.info file, it still says display_error Off. Searched for all php.ini file and changed all off to on but still same result. Help please

Answer (score 0):

Use **error_reporting();** at the begining of your PHP main file. It will ignore php.ini and obey the error level you set there.

Also, check that your php.ini is not beign use / locked before you make changes on it?

Comment: rally curious to know why this happened in first place ... i never happened to me

Comment: The file might be in use by the apache daemon at the time you try ti edit and save, you can also lack of the proper "rights" to save the php.ini file; sometimes its created only to be used by "apache user" whatever that user might be in your system.